# Word for something taken as given in a claim

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm writing an essay for a critical thinking course, and I'm evaluating the following claim:

> Without application in the world, the value of knowledge is greatly diminished.

What is a word for the phrase "Without application in the world"? I considered the "predicate" of the claim, but it doesn't seem to fit. It's also not quite a "prerequisite", either. 
[This](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93945/what-do-you-call-a-past-participlenoun-construction-clause-such-as-no-offense) question seemed similar, but doesn't quite answer my question.

I'm looking to finish the sentence
In order to evaluate the claim as a whole, we must take the ~~~ as true, however, this is not necessarily the case either.

Comment: I think the first part of the sentence is known as a "defining relative clause". I am not very sure about it, hence offering it as comment.

Comment: At least in the context of law,  something taken as given in a claim is termed a [_stipulation_](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/stipulation). But in your context, perhaps _postulate_ would be a more suitable term.

Comment: If regarded as a conditional ("If knowledge has no application in the world, then its value is greatly diminished"), then the first part would be a [protasis](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/protasis), in terms of grammar, or an [antecedent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/antecedent?s=t), in terms of logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would [premise](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/premise) work for you?
*a proposition supporting or helping to support a conclusion.*

"if the premise is true, then the conclusion must be true"

Answer (score 1):

"Postulate"(N) would be a good word as the Oxford dictionary assigns the definition to mean a hypothesis that is advanced to position or role of a claim or premise. What is significant is that the definition makes no remark as to whether the hypothesis has to be tested.

Answer (score 0):

*...it is considered **axiomatic** that ...* (admitted first principle; self-evident; indisputably true (OED).